# Put specific text at the end of file in unix

Tags: unix

I have a html file retrieved using `wget`. I want to put all links, i.e., all `<a href=""> </a>`, at the end of file. Is it possible?

For example, consider the following file:

```
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br /><a href="link.html">link</a>
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to change the text into this:

```
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br />
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
<a href="link.html">link</a>
```

Comment: Have you tried anything specific?

Comment: A proper way would probably involve XSLT...

Comment: Yeah, it's possible.  It probably isn't sensible.  Which tools are you willing to consider?  Perl has modules for parsing HTML; Python does too.  You could try games with `awk`, but that's likely to be messier (using regexes for parsing HTML is not recommended).

Comment: i would prefer `awk` but can you give specific example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to *copy* (and not *moving*) the links to the end of the file you can do a simple `grep` (maybe doesn't work for special cases of course):

```
grep -o -P '(<a href=.*?</a>)' test.html > tmp.html && cat tmp.html >> test.html
```

Answer (score 2):

For the simple anchor tag in the example data, this Perl script suffices:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @urls = ();

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    if (m/\s*(<a\s+[^>]+>.*<\/a>)\s*/)
    {
        push @urls, $1;
        s///;
    }
    print "$_\n";
}

foreach my $url (@urls)
{
    print "$url\n";
}
```

Example output:

```
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br />
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
<a href="link.html">link</a>
```

Note that if there were several anchor tags on a single line in the input, it will include the material between the outer tags at the bottom of the script, too.  If an anchor tag is broken across lines, it will be ignored.  I have little doubt that there are HTML notations that can break this script (but I'm not sure what they are).

This is a minor step up from the simple script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @urls = ();

while (<>)
{
    chomp;
    while (m/\s*(<a\s+[^>]+>.*?<\/a>)\s*/)
    {
        push @urls, $1;
        s// /;
    }
    print "$_\n";
}

foreach my $url (@urls)
{
    print "$url\n";
}
```

The `while` loop in place of the `if` iterates over matches in a line.  The non-greedy `.*?` quantifier means it does not gobble intermediate anchor tags.  The substitute replaces the removed material with a blank, thus keeping words separating the anchor tags separate.

Example data:

```
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br /><a href="link.html">link</a>
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br /> <a href="link2.html">link</a> extraneous material <a href="link3.html">link</a> other notes <a href="link4.html">link</a>
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
```

Example output:

```
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br /> 
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
<tr style="background-color: #EFEFEF">
    <td valign="top">Line1<br />2013.05.23</td>
    <td>Line2
    <br /> extraneous material other notes 
    <br />Line3
    </td>
</tr>
<a href="link.html">link</a>
<a href="link2.html">link</a>
<a href="link3.html">link</a>
<a href="link4.html">link</a>
```

You get to judge whether this is sufficient for your purposes.  At least it gives you something to work on.